# Iron Router: Route only works if URL is visited through the application

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

In my meteor application I have blog posts and the routes to the blog post will be http://localhost:3000/blog/test.

For some reason the page for each blog post will only load the data if the page is visited through the application. How can I have the route work with out being visiting through the application? So I could tweet http://localhost:3000/blog/test and when people visisted the link the blog pages data would be there.

here is the route for the blog pages

```js
Router.route('/blog/:slug', {
    name: 'articlePage',
    layoutTemplate: 'articlePage',
    data: function() {
        var post;
        post = Articles.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
        SEO.set({
          title: post.title,
          meta: {
            'description': post.body
          },
          og: {
            'title': post.title,
            'description': post.body
          }
        });
        return post;
    }
});
```

Here is the link clicked to visit the route that will load the data.

```html
<a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}" class="panel-link">
```

EDIT:

Here is subscription code

```js
articleSearchkeyword = Session.get('article-search-query');
articlesHandle = Meteor.subscribeWithPagination("articles", articleSearchkeyword, 12);
```

Comment: my money is you not handling your subscriptions quite right. I bet you you subscribe in a different route, so when that is hit first, your client got the data, and otherwise it doesn't. In the above you are not subscribing to anything. Can you show your code where you subscribe to collections?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply and thank you for helping. I have added my subscription code, I hope it helps with the diagnosis!

Comment: is this run in the global client scope or in a different place? also where do you set `article-search-query`?

Comment: my money is on the session variable not being set.

Comment: Jeremy, I was able to fix the session variable so it always has some sort of value but this only made the routes work for my development environment, whenever I deploy the app the routes still do not work.